# pdflatex killed when starting compilation in Texstudio

Tags: macos, tex, pdflatex

I have the following problem:

I have a rather large tex file to compile, including pgfplots, which take a while to compile, when using no externalize function. I switched from Windows with Miktex to a Mac with TexLive. When I start the compilation with

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex -shell-escape -output-directory=build -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

it works fine. When I start the compilation within Texstudio (F1), it compiles, when I comment parts of the file, no matter which one it is. However, when the compilation takes too long (mostly after exactly 30s), the compilation crashes, leaving the .aux and the .log unfinished, but without any error message. When I start texstudio from the command line and compile with F1, the error

`QProcess: Destroyed while process ("/usr/texbin/pdflatex") is still running`.

is printed in the terminal. Some research brought me to the function waitForFinished(), which apparently has a timeout after 30s. Searching for that function in the texstudio folder with grep gave no result.

Has anyone of you got a clue why this is happening and how to stop it? I don't give a minimum working example, since the file compiles alright in the terminal and also from texstudio, when commenting some part of it, no matter which.